# Excel: get cell collection of cells that contain certain text or formula

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, vba

I have a worksheet with 1 or more sheets and numerous filled cells per worksheet. I need to go through all cells that have a certain text and/or formula.

What is the quickest way to do this (in .NET)?

An example in VBA, VB.NET or C# would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Paste this macro in your macro editor in your workbook (ALT+F11)

```
Sub test()
  Dim w As Worksheet, r As Range
  For Each w In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each r In w.UsedRange
        If r.Value = "Certain text" Or r.Formula = "Certain Formula" Then
            'Do what you want to do here
        End If
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

Hope this helps